# How to play audio in ms webview2 on a a winform app?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, background, webview2

I have a website which I use to show task list and other info on a tv screen, this site plays audio when a new item is poped in the list.

At the moment I've to create a WinForms app to show my page on fullscreen on a windows pc. I created a small C# app that use a webview2 component from Microsoft, but it won't play audio when it is out of focus, does anybody has a solution for this problem?

Comment: If it's fullscreen, then it must have focus, right?

Comment: Yes, but it a dual screeen setup so sometimes happens the other monitoring software catch the focus.